# TypeScript Yup schema validation and Type Inference

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, yup

I currently have the following data type:

```js
type TPlan =
  | {
      type: "pro";
      content: { signedAt: string; expiresOn: string };
    }
  | {
      type: "default" | "regular";
      content: { signedAt: string };
    };
```

And taking into account the previous data type, I defined a schema for each structure of the object:

```js
const schemaA = object({
  type: mixed<"pro">().oneOf(["pro"]).defined(),
  content: object({
    signedAt: string().defined(),
    expiresOn: string().defined(),
  }),
});

const schemaB = object({
  type: mixed<"default" | "regular">().oneOf(["default", "regular"]).defined(),
  content: object({
    signedAt: string().defined(),
  }),
});
```

When I do the individual inference of the schemas, the data types are correct, as follows:

```js
type TSchemaA = InferType<typeof schemaA>;
type TSchemaB = InferType<typeof schemaB>;
```

However, when I go to define the validation schema, where I use the `.oneOf()` method, TypeScript says that the data types are incorrect. I did it this way:

```js
export const validationSchema = mixed<TSchemaA | TSchemaB>()
  .oneOf([schemaA, schemaB])
  .defined();
```

And my question is the following, how can I create a validation schema using Yup taking into account the initial type (`TPlan`)? Because in addition to needing the validation schemas to validate the JSON objects, I will also need the inference of the schemas to be correct as well.

Comment: I had very similar case. AFAIK, yup don't have nice support for unions

Answer (score 0):

```
export const validationSchema = mixed<TSchemaA | TSchemaB>()
  .oneOf([schemaA, schemaB])
  .defined();
```

This will not do what you want.
It will create a yup schema that could be used to validate TSchemaA or TSchemaB. But you do not want to validate schema, you want to validate data.

Here is my proposal :

```
const schemaPro = yup.object({
    type: yup.mixed<"pro">().oneOf(["pro"]).required(),
    content: yup
        .object({
            signedAt: yup.string().required(),
            expiresOn: yup.string().required(),
        })
        .required(),
});
const schemaDefaultOrRegular = yup.object({
    type: yup.mixed<"default" | "regular">().oneOf(["default", "regular"]).required(),
    content: yup.object({
        signedAt: yup.string().required(),
    }),
});
```

then this helper that will validate against multiple schema :

```
const validateOneOf = async (schemas: yup.AnySchema[], value: unknown): Promise<TPlan> => {
    for (const schema of schemas) {
        try {
            return await schema.validate(value, { stripUnknown: true });
        } catch (e) {
            // I know you can create a yup error, that concat all error for the loop. 
            // then you should be able to fire it at the end.
        }
    }

    throw new yup.ValidationError("No schema validated");
};
```

I have casted output as TPlan, that should be ok for your case.

then call it :

```
try {
        const plan: TPlan = await validateOneOf([schemaPro, schemaDefaultOrRegular], {
            type: "default",
            content: { signedAt: undefined, expiresOn: "456" },
        });
  
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("ERROR " + e);
    }
```